# How to know if an object is already bounded

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, bind

### Background:

According to the [MDN bind docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#description):

> A bound function can be further bound by calling boundFn.bind(thisArg, /* more args */), which creates another bound function boundFn2. The newly bound thisArg value is ignored..

This code from the docs is showing how "new this value" (thisArg of boundLog2) is being ignored:

```js
"use strict"; // prevent `this` from being boxed into the wrapper object

function log(...args) {
  console.log(this, ...args);
}
const boundLog = log.bind("this value", 1, 2);
const boundLog2 = boundLog.bind("new this value", 3, 4);
boundLog2(5, 6); // "this value", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

### A question:

When importing objects from libraries, something like this:

```js
import obj from library
```

Is there any way to check ahead if `obj` is already bounded?

I want to know if `obj` is the result of some previous `bind` call, is this possible?

Comment: This feels like a design decision - you shouldn't need to know about a functions implementation to know how you can use it. Binding a function to your own thing should be reflected in how the exposed function is named or documented. Quoting MDN `These values are stored in advance, instead of being passed at call time. You can generally see const boundFn = fn.bind(thisArg, arg1, arg2) as being equivalent to const boundFn = (...restArgs) => fn.call(thisArg, arg1, arg2, ...restArgs) for the effect when it's called (but not when boundFn is constructed).`

Comment: as an example image `function add(b) {return this + b}; const addTwo = add.bind(2);` here addTwo communicates the new purpose of the function and the implementation detail of this being used in add is lost to the caller of addTwo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#bound_function you can infer it from the function's `.name`. When a function is being bounded, the prefix "bound " is added to the original name and being set as the bounded function's name.

```js
function isBoundedFunction(func) {
    return typeof func === 'function' &&
        func.name.slice(0, 6) === 'bound ';
}

const namedFunc = () => {}
const boundedFunc = namedFunc.bind("some value");
const boundedAnonimousFunc = (() => {}).bind("some value");

console.log(namedFunc.name, isBoundedFunction(namedFunc));
console.log(boundedFunc.name, isBoundedFunction(boundedFunc));
console.log(boundedAnonimousFunc.name, isBoundedFunction(boundedAnonimousFunc));
```

Though, I can agree with the commenter who said that it's not something you are usually supposed to do.

Comment: Wow! Although I could not resist to look up how to break that detection: Turns out you can `Object.defineProperty(namedFunc, 'name', {value:'bound namedFunc'})` or define a name using a symbol with allows a String `{[Symbol("bound f")]:()=>{}}`

Comment: @Simon I agree, some things in JS are easily breakable if someone really wants to. You can override or cheat many of the built-in methods.